# How can I reorder the x axis in a plot in R?

Tags: r, plot

Using `plot` in R causes the factors on the x-axis to be alphabetically ordered.

How can I specify the order of the factors on the x-axis?

Example:

```
y <- 1:9
x <- c(rep("B", 3), rep("A", 3), rep("C", 3))
plot(y ~ as.factor(x))
```

This results in:

[image]

How can I get this to plot as "B", "A", "C"?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You just need to specify the levels of your factor in the order you want. So here I create a new variable `x1`

```
x1  = factor(x, levels=c("B", "C", "A"))
```

where

```
R> x1
[1] B B B A A A C C C
Levels: B C A
```

The `plot` function now works as expected.

```
plot(y ~ x1)
```

Comment: More discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587111/setting-levels-when-creating-a-factor-vs-levels

Answer (score 7):

It looks that you want to plot them in some form of order based on the 50% value of each box plot? Taking a different dataframe as an example:

```
temp <- structure(list(
  Grade = c("U","G", "F", "E", "D", "C", "B", "A", "A*"), 
  n = c(20L, 13L, 4L, 13L, 36L, 94L, 28L, 50L, 27L)), 
  .Names = c("Grade", "n"), 
  class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"), 
  row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

If we plot this, we can see that the labels are messed up (A comes before A*).

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(temp) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(x=Grade, y=n))
```

[image]

We could order this manually as shown above, or we could decide to plot the grades in order of number of students getting each grade. This can also be done manually, but it would be better if we could automate this:

First we order the dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)
temp <- temp %>% arrange(n)
```

Then we change the levels inside the `Grade` column to represent the order of the data

```
temp$Grade <- as.vector(temp$Grade) #get rid of factors
temp$Grade = factor(temp$Grade,temp$Grade) #add ordered factors back
```

Running the same graph command shown above gives you data plotted with an differently ordered x axis.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In ggplot, in lieu of changing the order of the data on the outside, you can also simply specify the order within the plot using:

```
+scale_x_discrete(limits = c("B","A","C"))
```

Of course this only works if you have a limited number of categories!

Answer (score 2):

I solved a problem similar to this using the command:

```r
scale_x_discrete()
```

in your case:

```r
scale_x_discrete(limits = c("B","A","C"))
```